Gauge function and counter function
I know that some functions are belong to gauge and some of them are for counter and we would get the wrong result if we don't use them correctly.
I search in the net but i didn't find any good result or resource for this.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me to find the good resource for finding out which functions we can use for gauges and which one for counter.

Functions that accept range-vector as an argument might might be specifically designed to be used with counter metrics. This comes down to the presence of mechanism to account for counter resets.
Following functions have said mechanism:

increase()
irate()
rate()
resets()

18 other functions accepting range-vectors don't have mentioned mechanism.
But it's important to understand, that all these functions, both accounting for resets and not, can be used for both counters and gauges, if you understand what you are doing.

Functions that take instant-vector as an argument can always be used with both gauges and counters.

Documentation for functions in Prometheus.

many thanks @markalex have another question and i know i have to ask in another post but i would appreciate if you could answer me here. my question is after relabeling, the new label stores in the tsdb and the old one removes or both exist in the tsdb or is it something else that i don't know?.consider that i am a newbie to prometheus and some concepts confuse me very much

@EmadKhavaninzadeh, it depends on what you mean by new and old here. And how relabeling is done. Relabeling doesn't work retrospectively, so all data that was scraped before change in config will stay the same. If you mean that you created new label (let's say env1 based on existing env, both labels will be stored, unless you specified original one to be dropped (also through relabeling).

@EmadKhavaninzadeh, I very much recommend asking this with full details as a separate post. But not on SO, as it's off-topic here. And of course search if it already was asked before.

Well the main categorization of functions that you need to understand before using is - if they operate on inputs instant-vector or range-vector inputs. The documentation clearly explains it.
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/
For your concern, most of the mathematical functions are more useful for gauges but can still be used on counters and they will work but would be meaningless.
Following are functions specific to counters mainly ->
increase()
irate()
rate()
resets()
Hope this helps.
